# How to fetch xml data from the url and display data in grid using angular Js custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular

I have `xml` data on a server. I want that data to be displayed in grid format in my html page using custom directive in angularJs.

It should display data when `acc-grid` directive is called

index.html:

```
<acc-grid myaccheaders=”ID,Name,DateOfJoining,Keywords” data=”request.data”>
</grid-view>
```